# How to call a Java method on any read/write access of a database column through Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a two-column database table that contains a mapping of usernames to payload values.

```
+ -------- | ------- +
| username | payload |
+ ---------| --------+
| foobar   | 123.abc |
+ ---------| --------+
```

For various (admittedly stupid, but unavoidable) reasons, the payload (a String) needs to be stored in a weird *pseudo-reverse* order (basically a reversible hash - 'abc.123' is stored as '123.abc').

I've written a method to do the reversal of the value which works fine:
`public String reversePayload(validPayload) {...}`

Is there a way that I can configure Hibernate to call that function whenever it reads or writes from/to the `payload` column, so that I can have the code that actually uses that payload value deal with it in "standard" form?

(I've already tried modifying the DAO to do it - which I think will work - but our DAO isn't really abstracted very nicely, and I ended up having to add 10 different calls to `reversePayload`, one for every method that calls `currentSession().saveOrUpdate(user)` or `currentSession().get('<username>')`)

Answer (score 1):

How about creating two properties - leaving the raw value transient, and mapping the converted value to a column. Your DAOs can then remain blissfully ignorant of what's going on.

```
...

String payload;

...

@Transient
public String getPayload()
{
   return payload;
}

public void setPayload(String payload)
{
   this.payload = payload;
}

@Column(name = "payload")
public String getReversedPayload()
{
   return reverse(getPayload());
}

public void setReversedPayload(String reversedPayload)
{
   setPayload(unreverse(reversedPayload));
}
```

You could also make a custom Hibernate Type, or (less for the faint hearted) a custom Interceptor.

Comment: Oh, I like this. What source file to these get applied in?

Comment: Your mapped model class - in your case, whatever `user` is.

Comment: We're using a `hibernate-mapping` XML doc for that mapping - is there an equivalent to `@transient` for that?

Comment: If you're using XML then just don't map the transient field.

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.1 has a standard way to define custom types that allow doing exactly what you want.

If not using JPA 2.1, Hibernate also allows defining your own custom types: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-custom

This has the advantage of being able to use the proper value even in HQL query parameters: Hibernate will reverse the value passed as parameter before binding it to the SQL statement.